# listen tcp 127.0.4.1:2040: bind: can't assign requested address

Tags: macos, http, go, tcp, localhost

I am using this golang code:

```
l, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.4.1:2040")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("d0b9184a-5248-413e-a5a8-30fea66997f5:", err)
}

log.Fatal(s.Serve(l))
```

I am getting this error:

> listen tcp 127.0.4.1:2040: bind: can't assign requested address

anyone know why that won't work?

Comment: Does your machine have 127.0.4.1 IP address? ping 127.0.4.1 or issue ipconfig/all

Comment: does this show anything ? `ifconfig -a | grep "127.0.4.1"`

Comment: that commands returns an empty set

Comment: This should work. But there are 255 addresses in 127.0.1: why not use 127.0.1.4?

Comment: this ip does not seem to exist on this host. Did you mean `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: I meant what I said. All those 127.* addresses should work.

Comment: @user207421: all 127.0.0.0/8 address are _valid_ and routed through loopback, but you can't bind to a specific address that's not assigned to an interface on all platforms (macos in this case).

Comment: @JimB that sounds accurate can you add an answer?

Comment: The code does not show how the Server s is defined. Is if possible to view the parameters ?

Comment: @JimB they're not routed through loopback on macOS - just the `127.0.0.1` works. One can easily add/remove them with `sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.4.1`/`sudo ifconfig lo0 -alias 127.0.4.1` for example - then they're routed through loopback & bindable.

Comment: thanks @zrzka, maybe I should have said "routable", otherwise that is exactly what I was getting at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add an additional IPv4 address to the loopback interface:

```sh
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.4.1
```

Before running the command you can verify the routes using:

```sh
netstat -nr
```

By default (On MacOS Catalina 10.15.4), these routes are present:

```sh
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
```

After you have added your desired address to the loopback interface (i.e, lo0), `netstat -nr` would show:

```sh
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0
127.0.4.1          127.0.4.1          UH             lo0
```

Now try using your program, it should work.

Also, this is temporary. It won't persist on reboot. For that give this a [read](https://blog.felipe-alfaro.com/2017/03/22/persistent-loopback-interfaces-in-mac-os-x/)!

Comment: so would `127.0.0.1:3000` conflict with `127.0.4.1:3000` or are they truly different addresses?

Comment: Ports (UDP or TCP) have their own pool (range) per IP address. So, yes `127.0.0.1:3000` and `127.0.4.1:3000` will work.

Comment: Hi, @AlexChannelmeter if this answer has solved your query, then could you please consider accepting it.

Comment: havent tested it yet, but will soon, ty